# Serve html file using firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

How can I serve `index.html` file located in my `blog` folder by using a firebase function.

Here is my file tree

```
FirebaseWebsite
  │   
  ├── blog
  │   ├── index.html
  │   ├── css
  │   │   ├── fonts
  │   │   │   ├── FontAwesome.otf
  │   │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
  │   │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
  │   │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
  │   │   │   └── fontawesome-webfont.woff
  │   │   ├── images
  │   │   │   └── banner.jpg
  │   │   └── style.css
  │   ├── fancybox
  │   │   ├── blank.gif
  │   │   ├── fancybox_loading.gif
  │   │   ├── fancybox_loading@2x.gif
  │   │   ├── fancybox_overlay.png
  │   │   ├── fancybox_sprite.png
  │   │   ├── fancybox_sprite@2x.png
  │   │   ├── helpers
  │   │   │   ├── fancybox_buttons.png
  │   │   │   ├── jquery.fancybox-buttons.css
  │   │   │   ├── jquery.fancybox-buttons.js
  │   │   │   ├── jquery.fancybox-media.js
  │   │   │   ├── jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css
  │   │   │   └── jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js
  │   │   ├── jquery.fancybox.css
  │   │   ├── jquery.fancybox.js
  │   │   └── jquery.fancybox.pack.js
  │   ├── js
  │   │   └── script.js
  │   └── tags
  │       └── Topic-for-blog
  │           └── index.html
  ├── index.js
  │
  ├── functions
  │      └── index.js
  │
  ├── Public
  │      └── aboutUs.html
  │
  └── firebase.json
```

Here is the firebase function that I am using

`index.js` (from **functions** folder)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express   = require('express');
const blogApp   = express();

blogApp.get('/blog', (request, response) => {

    response.sendfile('../blog/public/index.html');
});

exports.blogApp = functions.https.onRequest(blogApp);
```

Below is the configuration

`firebase.json`

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/blog",
        "function": "blogApp"
      }
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true
  }
}
```

Below is the error that I am getting when I visit the [url](http://CurieDoc.com/blog)

> Refused to load the image '' because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that
>   'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy your functions, everything in the `functions` folder is packaged up and sent to Cloud Functions.  Nothing outside of that folder is sent, which means that your `blog` folder is not available at runtime (nor is your static web content deployed to Firebase Hosting).  If you want to contents of `blog` to be readable at runtime by your deployed code, it should live in the `functions` folder before you run the deploy command.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to serve `index.html` file from the firebase `functions` folder, however, I was not able to serve the corresponding static files (.css, images etc) from the firebase `functions` folder. e.g. `style.css` file is empty and other folders with images are missing. Please see the updated folder tree in my question.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually serving index.html from the function?  It was more likely that Firebase Hosting was serving it directly, overriding the function.

Comment: Hey, do you remember how you solved for this? I am on the same boat right now. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.